# Rails - Aliasing Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, alias

I'm working on an application that has a gallery in it. I have three models, `Gallery`, `GalleryType`, `GalleryImage`. The Associations are such that a `Gallery` belongs to a `GalleryType`, a `Gallery` has many `GalleryImages`, and lastly, I want the Gallery to have one featured image, of type `GalleryImage`. I've been looking at polymorphic associations on the Rails Site, but I can't figure out exactly how to make this work.

I'm using paperclip, and I know I can just `has_attached_file :featured_image`, but there are methods in the `GalleryImage` model that I want to use on the featured_image, and it seems really redundant to make another class for featured image when it's exactly the same as the `GalleryImage`.

How can I "alias" the model as an arbitrary name so that `Gallery.featured_image` resolves to a similar association as `Gallery.gallery_images`, except singular?

Comment: you could use a `featured` column in `GalleryImage`, I don't see polymorphic association is needed to save that. Maybe I did not understand the purpose you explained to use polymorphic association.

Comment: man, I feel stupid after reading that... I got it working another way, albeit in a way that was way more tedious